# How to attend image to pygame window based on paths from array?

Tags: python, arrays, pygame

I'm trying to build a mobile interface in `pygame`. I have a folder called apps and every app contains two files: "`app.py`" and "`app.png`". Currently I can get the app name the folder contents. the file contents are saved in an array. I am trying to get the "`app.png`" from every folder and add it to the `pygame` screen?

Here is my current code:

```
from pygame import *
import os
import pygame
import time
import random

_image_library = {}

class SeedOS():

    def home(self):
        def get_image(path):
            global _image_library
            image = _image_library.get(path)
            if image == None:
                canonicalized_path = path.replace('/', os.sep).replace('\\', os.sep)
                image = pygame.image.load(canonicalized_path)
                _image_library[path] = image
            return image
        (width, height) = (240, 320)
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Seed OS')
        BLACK = (0,0,0)
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        apps = os.walk("apps").next()[1]
        app_count = 0
        while app_count < len(apps):
            print apps[app_count]
            icon_width = 0
            icon_height = 0
            screen.blit(get_image("apps/" + apps[app_count] + "/app.png"), (icon_width, 0))
            icon_width+=70
            app_count += 1
        pygame.display.flip()
        running = True
        while running:
          for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              running = False
phone = SeedOS()
phone.home()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that `icon_width` is getting re-initialized to zero with each iteration through the `while-loop`:

```
while app_count < len(apps):
    print apps[app_count]
    icon_width = 0
    icon_height = 0
    screen.blit(get_image("apps/" + apps[app_count] + "/app.png"), (icon_width, 0))
    icon_width+=70
    app_count += 1
```

So the `screen.blit` will always place the image at `(0, 0)`;  `icon_width+=70` is nugatory. Instead you could use something like:

```
icon_width = 0
icon_height = 0
max_width = 240  # <-- you'll need to decide how to set this, depending on size of screen
while app_count < len(apps):
    print apps[app_count]
    screen.blit(get_image("apps/" + apps[app_count] + "/app.png"), 
                (icon_width, icon_height))
    icon_width += 70
    if icon_width > max_width:
        icon_width = 0
        icon_height += 70 # <-- assuming app.pngs have constant height
    app_count += 1
```

This is still pretty rudimentary -- it does not address the possibility of
different sized `app.png`s nor what to do if there are more images than can fit
on the screen. But this should get you over the first hump -- how to place the images at different locations.